# How to assign created_at to another column name in legacy DB with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails and have a legacy DB that contains DateCreated and DateUpdated columns in each table. I'd like to use the builtin created_at and updated_at attributes in my models to set these fields prior to a save but my attempts yield: 
NoMethodError (undefined method `created_at' for #<Class:0x00000102b74d20>):
  app/models/user.rb:45:in`set_create_update_time'
  app/models/user.rb:24:in `block in <class:User>'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:15:in`create'

Model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :user_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :DateCreated,     :DateUpdated
alias_attribute :email, :Email
alias_attribute :user_name, :UserName
alias_attribute :remember_token, :RememberToken

self.table_name = "adm.User"
self.primary_key = "UserId"


has_secure_password
before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
before_save { set_create_update_time}
before_save :create_remember_token

#validations
validates :user_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 8}
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = 
/\A[\w+\-.]+@[ a-z\ d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
#  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {    case_sensitive: false} 



private 
  def create_remember_token
  # Create the token
  self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
```

end

```
def set_create_update_time
 self.DateCreated = created_at
 self.DateUpdated = updated_at
end

end
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, if your model has fields `created_at` and `updated_at` named exactly like this then ActiveRecord will set/update them accordingly. In your case, since you have your own attributes, you will need to update them manually.

You're on the right track. Your issue is that on the right-hand side you're referencing a non-existent method/variable `created_at` - which is what that exception is saying.

I'd make callbacks like this - which set the attributes to the current time:

```
before_create :set_created_at
before_save :set_updated_at

def set_created_at
  if DateCreated.blank?
    self.DateCreated = Time.now.utc
  end
end

def set_updated_at
  self.DateUpdated = Time.now.utc
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `self.created_at` and `self.updated_at`. Only then the instance attributes of the object (user record) will be accessed.

And also you might want to do an `after_update` callback to update the `DateUpdated` attribute.

And may I know why you are creating aliases and changing the naming style? It is a convention in Rails to use `attribute_name` style for attributes and methods and `MyClass` style for Classes.

Comment: Thanks for the response however, self.created_at still gives NoMethodError exception. I'm creating aliases b/c I have a legacy DB that doesn't conform to the rails naming convention and I don't have the ability to change the column names on the DB itself

Comment: Alright. Alright. I thought you had created_at and updated_at fields in your database and thought you just wanted to copy them over to DateCreated and DateUpdated. Good luck!